# Handling $scope in typescript code for angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

The following works where $scope and $mdDialog are static.

```
declare var module: any;
export interface IChangePassword extends ng.IScope {
    cancel: Function;
    myname: string;
    state: string;
    processRequest: Function;
    CurrentPassword: string;
    NewPassword: string;
    ConfirmPassword: string;
}

export class ChangePasswordController {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$mdDialog","$timeout"];
    static $mdDialog: any;
    static $timeout: any;
    state: string = 'getInput';
    static $scope: IChangePassword;
    CurrentPassword: string;
    NewPassword: string;
    ConfirmPassword: string;
    ChangePasswordService: any;

    constructor($scope: IChangePassword, $mdDialog: any, $timeout: any) {
        ChangePasswordController.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
        ChangePasswordController.$scope = $scope;
        $scope.state = this.state;
        $scope.cancel = this.cancel;
        $scope.processRequest = this.processRequest;
       //this.ChangePasswordService = ChangePasswordService;
        ChangePasswordController.$timeout = $timeout;
    }

   public cancel ():void {
        ChangePasswordController.$mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    public processRequest(): void {
        ChangePasswordController.$scope.state = 'processRequest';
        ChangePasswordController.$timeout(function () {
            ChangePasswordController.$scope.state = 'Done';
        }, 5000);

    }


}

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.controller("ChangePasswordController", ChangePasswordController);
}
```

The following does not work. The object this.$scope is always null inside processRequest(). Please help.

```
export class ChangePasswordController {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$mdDialog","$timeout"];
    static $mdDialog: any;
    static $timeout: any;
    state: string = 'getInput';
    $scope: IChangePassword;
    CurrentPassword: string;
    NewPassword: string;
    ConfirmPassword: string;
    ChangePasswordService: any;
    //myname: string = 'gaurav';
    constructor($scope: IChangePassword, $mdDialog: any, $timeout: any) {
        ChangePasswordController.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
        this.$scope = $scope;
        $scope.state = this.state;
        $scope.cancel = this.cancel;
        $scope.processRequest = this.processRequest;
       //this.ChangePasswordService = ChangePasswordService;
        ChangePasswordController.$timeout = $timeout;
    }

   public cancel ():void {
        ChangePasswordController.$mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    public processRequest(): void {
        this.$scope.state = 'processRequest';
        ChangePasswordController.$timeout(function () {
            this.state = 'Done';
        }, 5000);

    }


}

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.controller("ChangePasswordController", ChangePasswordController);
}
```

I am not sure why the $scope is not available as an instance variable. in this code. Please let me know if there is a better way to write this code.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you pass `processRequest` to `$scope` without binding the current object as `this` for the function. In Javascript, `this` is determined by the caller not by the declaration context. You can either use `bind` to tie the current object to the function, or use an arrow function which captures `this` from the declaration context:

```
$scope.processRequest = this.processRequest.bind(this);
$scope.processRequest = () => this.processRequest();
```